# MySQL: How to update rows data equals other row in the same table?

Tags: mysql, csv, sql-update, mysqlimport

I have the current table structure (simplified) with many more populated columns that I don't want to lose.

```
 id |           url          | atrib1 | atrib2 |atrib3
 1  | http://example.com/123 |        |        | 
 2  | http://example.com/545 |        |        |  
 3  | http://example.com/323 |        |        |
```

AND the following CSV file:

```
id |           url          | atrib1 | atrib2 |atrib3
1  | http://example.com/123 | 195    | 65     | 15
2  | http://example.com/545 | 185    | 55     | 14
3  | http://example.com/323 | 205    | 70     | 18
```

Now what I want to do is to link the values from the `atrib1`, `atrib2`, `atrib3` column of the csv to the existing values from `url` column from the MySQL table.

PS: I thought to add an extra `link2` from the csv like:

```
INSERT INTO table(link2,atrib1,atrib2,atrib3) VALUES ('http://example.com/123','185','65','15') WHERE url2 = url;


id |           url2         | atrib1 | atrib2 |atrib3
1  | http://example.com/123 | 195    | 65     | 15
2  | http://example.com/545 | 185    | 55     | 14
3  | http://example.com/323 | 205    | 70     | 18
```

But what I was thinking at is not ok.

The problem is I didn't find a way to do this. How this can be done?

Comment: Have you took a look on this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-into-a-mysql-table-or-update-if-exists

Comment: I think @Jaumzera has the right idea here. That's what I'd do if you can `UNIQUE` the `url2` column.

Comment: Can you help me with some demo code so i can understand?